# CakePHP Recaptcha plugin being called twice

Tags: cakephp, captcha, recaptcha

Well, i have been struggling this for almost a day now... Yet I cant figure out why my recaptcha plugin is being called twice. I suspect, my paypal plugin is also being called twice for sure. I really have no idea why my components are being called twice coz i know it is not possible for a plugin actions to be called twice if it is loaded twice. Any inputs/ideas will be highly appreciated. please help. I hate problems that don't give me much clues on where to look first. Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I noticed that reCAPTCHA was always failing validation and determined that it was being called twice and the second time always failed, I assume because the reCAPTCHA library is only designed to allow for a given challenge to be validated once.

In my case, it was being called twice because I was manually calling `Model::validate()` before `Model::save()`, which also validates unless if told not to. I fixed the issue by turning off validation in the call to save (`Model::save(null, false)`).